# Не понятная ошибка в коде ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Tags: python

вот такой вот код:

```
class Games:
    def knb(self):
        user_stats = 1

        print(f"Добро пожаловать в игру: Камень, ножницы, бумага.\nТебе нужно набрать 10 очков.\nТвои очки: {user_stats}")
        while True:
            tmp = ["камень", "ножницы", "бумага"]
            u = input("выбери: (к/н/б)")
            c = random.choice(tmp)
            if u == "к" and c == "камень":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ничья. Твои очки: {user_stats}")
            if u == "к" and c == "ножницы":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты победил. Твои очки: {user_stats: += 1}")
            if u == "к" and c == "бумага":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты проиграл. Твои очки: {user_stats: -= 1}")
            if u == "н" and c == "камень":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты проиграл. Твои очки: {user_stats: -= 1}")
            if u == "н" and c == "ножницы":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ничья. Твои очки: {user_stats}")
            if u == "н" and c == "бумага":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты победил. Твои очки: {user_stats: += 1}")
            if u == "б" and c == "камень":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты победил. Твои очки: {user_stats: += 1}")
            if u == "б" and c == "ножницы":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ты проиграл. Твои очки: {user_stats: -= 1}")
            if u == "б" and c == "бумага":
                print(f"бот выбрал {c}")
                print(f"ничья. Твои очки: {user_stats}")
            if user_stats == 10:
                print("ты прошёл игру!")
                sys.exit()
            if user_stats == 0:
                print("если твои очки будут меньше 0, то ты проиграешь")
            if user_stats < 0:
                sys.exit()
```

выводит уже другую ошибку, т.к я немного видоизменил код, добавив после user_stats ":" по просьбе одного комментатора:

```
print(f"ты победил. Твои очки: {user_stats: += 1}")
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Comment: теперь у меня ошибка другая, уже когда вычислять пытается: ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Comment: Почитай ошибку, посмотри где она возникает и немного подумай. Можешь почитать по f-строки. Должно помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо неправильных выражений типа

```
{user_stats: += 1}
```

(в f-строках параметров функций `print()`)

просто перед каждой такой командой `print(...)` измените значение переменной `user_stats` присвоением

```
user_stats += 1
```

и затем в самой команде `print(...)` используйте только `{user_stats}`.

(Подобным образом, конечно, для всех `{user_stats: -= 1}`.)

---

*Объяснение:*

После двоеточия (`:`) ожидается *спецификация формата*, например `05d`,
а ваше  `+= 1` или  `-= 1` *не является правильной спецификацией*.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем нужен `+= 1`? Без этого нормально выводится отображение очков. Если с этим связана какая-то логика, то её нужно прописать отдельно, а не в print.

Comment: нет, не нормально, потому что в программе у меня прописано, что если у меня будет < 0 очков - программа останавливается, и даже больше скажу, из 0 не вычитается, пишет 0, даже программа не останавливается.

Comment: @Loverツ сюдя по тому, что у вас не одна проблема, то лучше показать весь код полностью.

Comment: вот, наблюдайте, может ошибку найдёте.